# CRM 2015 : Custom Ribbon buttons in quote entity not visible after the quote is activated

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have added a custom button on the ribbon for the quote entity form.
The button is visible and is working as expected when the quote is in draft state.

When I click on the Activate Quote button, the quote becomes active. This action also refreshes the ribbon. After the ribbon is refreshed, I do not see the custom buttons that I had added in the ribbon anymore.

I checked in ribbon workbench and the custom button I added does not have any display rules defined which might cause it to be hidden on Activate quote.
I also checked for any custom scripts which might cause this behavior but I could not find any which would make the custom buttons to be not visible.

I tried adding the custom button to a different group in the ribbon but that doesn't seem to help either.

It seems that the ribbon only shows a predefined set of controls on the quote entity form once the quote has been activated.
Does anyone has any suggestions on how I can circumvent this issue?

Below is the ribbondiffxml of the quote entity. The custom buttons that I added are "Copy Estimate" and "New Version"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RibbonDiffXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CustomActions>
    <CustomAction Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Form.quote.MainTab.Actions.Controls._children" Sequence="4">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Button Alt="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.Alt" Command="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Command" Description="Copy Estimate" Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button" Image32by32="$webresource:mcace_EntityRibbon_32x32.png" Image16by16="$webresource:mcace_EntityRibbon_16x16.png" LabelText="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.LabelText" Sequence="4" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.ToolTipDescription" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
    <CustomAction Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Form.quote.MainTab.Actions.Controls._children" Sequence="4">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Button Alt="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.Alt" Command="Sol.quote.Estimate.NewVersion.Command" Description="New Version" Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button" Image32by32="/_imgs/SFA/ReviseQuote_32.png" Image16by16="/_imgs/SFA/ReviseQuote_16.png" LabelText="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.LabelText" Sequence="4" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.ToolTipDescription" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
    <HideCustomAction HideActionId="Sol.Mscrm.Form.quote.ReviseQuote.Hide" Location="Mscrm.Form.quote.ReviseQuote" />
  </CustomActions>
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates" />
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions>
    <CommandDefinition Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Command">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.EnableRule" />
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="triggerCopyEntity" Library="$webresource:sol_Entity_Ribbon.js" />
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
    <CommandDefinition Id="Sol.quote.Estimate.NewVersion.Command">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.EnableRule" />
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="setIsNewVersionField" Library="$webresource:sol_Estimate_ribbon" />
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
  </CommandDefinitions>
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.DisplayRule.DisplayRule">
        <CrmClientTypeRule Type="Web" Default="true" />
      </DisplayRule>
    </DisplayRules>
    <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.EnableRule">
        <FormStateRule State="Existing" Default="false" InvertResult="false" />
      </EnableRule>
    </EnableRules>
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.LabelText">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Copy Estimate" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.ToolTipTitle">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Copy Estimate" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.ToolTipDescription">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Copy Estimate" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.Button.Alt">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Copy Estimate" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.LabelText">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="New Version" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.ToolTipTitle">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="New Version" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.ToolTipDescription">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="New Version" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.NewVersion.Button.Alt">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="New Version" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
  </LocLabels>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing your actual Ribbon definition - could you copy the RibbonDiff Xml from the Ribbon Workbench and add it to your question?

Comment: @Filburt : Thanks for your response. I have edited the question to include the ribbonDiif XML as well. Let me know in case there is any other information I can add which will help the readers get a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your EnableRule `Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.EnableRule` to negate the create-state.

Your modified rule should look like this:

```
<EnableRules>
  <EnableRule Id="Sol.Form.Estimate.CopyEntity.EnableRule">
    <FormStateRule State="Create" InvertResult="true" />
  </EnableRule>
</EnableRules>
```

So instead of formulating

```
bool enable = FormState == Existing
```

MS CRM expects

```
bool enable = !(FormState == Create)
```

MS concept of Enable- and DisplayRules turned out to be strange more than once to me as well.

Comment: You are right. While trying to figure out the issue, I saw that the command bar will not display disabled items. The way I had written the enable rule, it will only be true for update form. Since the form state changes to read only, my rule fails and the Enable rule evaluates to false. I'll change the rule as per your answer. That covers my requirement in a much better way. Thanks for all the help.